# How to compute this limit? Which could be an example that Cauchy's first theorem doesn't hold for infinite limits.

Tags: calculus, geometry, analysis, limits

Compute $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum\limits_{k\geq 10}^n\dfrac{(\log(\log k))}{k}$. Actually this example comes to my mind in order to give a counter example that Cauchy's first theorem on limits doesn't hold for divergent sequences, i.e. if $\{a_n\} \rightarrow \infty $ then it is possible that  the sequence of averages $\{\dfrac{a_1+\cdots +a_n}{n}\}$ converges.

Comment: Try the integral test.  Note that the terms are larger than those in a harmonic series for large $k$.

Comment: If $a_n\to +\infty$ then $\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_n}{n}\to +\infty$. Such counter-example does not exist: if $a_n\geq M$ from some point on, the averaged sequence is $\geq M/2$ from some point on.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio any reference will be of great help. Thanks